# How to set a value to the specific key of an item in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

For example `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)))` this code sets new value to user object in local storage, but i want to set a value only, for example, to "name" key of user object in local storage.

How can i do that, and is that ecen possible?

I can use this piece of code to get that value:
`JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user")).name;`

But how can i set a value to that property?

Comment: You have to read and parse the value to an object, update the object, then serialise and write the object again. From local storage's perspective, it's **just a string**.

Answer (score 2):

you can set your value using the object you retrieve from localStorage and updating only this value and setting back the whole object:

```
const user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user"))

// you can do like this:
user.name = 'your new name'
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)))

// or
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
  ...user,
  name: 'your new name'
}))
```

Comment: glad to help... also don't forget to accept my answer as the sollution of your question if this is the case :)